# What is the output of a moore state machine?

Tags: vhdl, state-machine, digital-logic

I have a state machine diagram, but it does not have any output.
How will I know the output?
[image]

Comment: Every state is an output.  Is this some arbitrary drawing of circles and arrows, or is it a model of something specific?  A little context would help...

Comment: If you want to know the output, this is an incomplete diagram. The real output is the 3-bit state id, but when I was in school these state machine diagrams usually had a 1-bit output marked in the state bubble to show the result of the look up function between the state and a 1-bit output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output would be the state.
The x is assigned to a switch on a board.
A clock pulse is then a applied.
If x=0 or the switch is off, and a clock pulsed is applied, the 7-seg display will show 4.
There will be an infinite loop at state 7, which means that it will show 7 no matter what you do on the circuit once it reaches state 7.

Answer (score 0):

In Mealy state machine, the output depends of the current state and input but in Moore SM, the output only depends of the current state.
So you can consider that each state is an arbritrary output.